# Text values in a pivot table?

Tags: sql, excel, matrix, pivot-table

I have a table (in MySQL) with 3 columns:

```
Location    Category     Supplier

   A        Computers    Company X
   A        Printers     Company Y
   B        Computers    Company X
   B        Printers     Company Y
   B        Software     Company Y
   C        Computers    Company Y
   C        Software     Company Z
```

Now I need to make a matrix containing the above information, like this :

```
       Computers      Printers       Software

A      Company X      Company Y
B      Company X      Company Y      Company Y
C      Company Y                     Company Z
```

Eventually I need to have this in Excel.

In reality I have a variable number of categories, so doing it in MySQL with a join for each column is not a good option. I could write a function in PHP, but I was wondering if there's a more elegant solution.

I looked a pivot tables in Excel, but they seem more suited for numbers as values. But maybe I'm overlooking something, since I never work with Excel myself.

Any idea's?

Comment: [It sounds like you aren't using much of the MS stack, so I'm putting this as a comment, not answer.] SQL Server Reporting Services will handle this situation very well, and give you great Excel output. You could query the MySQL db from SSRS. But if you don't have MS SQL server, this is a bad option.

Comment: Have you tried using the pivot table with a Max aggregate function?

Comment: Tried, but doesn't work.

Comment: when I tried it on SSRS I get system.outofmemory exception.. geez I only had 4 columns and a few thousand records.. my entire set is 350,000 rows.   a macro can do it in a few minutes.. why does Excel not do this out of the box!?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem with pivot tables... Perfect for summaries, but not for text matrices.

I have just "lifted" some code examples that I used. Here I have the data in columns A-D and build the matrix (in the same sheet)  around column F.

Check to see if this helps.

I still have trouble getting the code to look right , so please be aware that a lot of the code starts before the code window.

Code Example 1:

```
'Fill in the values

Sheets("TempFile").Select

ListRow = 1

MisMatchCounter = 0

Do Until Cells(ListRow, 1).Value = ""

    ' Get table entry from third column of list.

    TableEntry = Cells(ListRow, 3).Value

    On Error Resume Next

    If Err.Number > 0 Then MsgBox Err.Number

    ' Get position of product name within range of row titles.

    If TableEntry <> "" Then

        TableRow = Application.Match(Cells(ListRow, 1), Range("F3:" & MYLastRowAddress), 0) ' 2 rows less than reality

        ' Get position of product size within range of column titles.

        TableColumn = Application.Match(Cells(ListRow, 2), Range("G2:" & MYLastColAddress), 0)

        Set CellToFill = Range("F2").Offset(TableRow, TableColumn)

        ' If there's already an entry in the cell, separate it from the new entry with a comma and space.

        If Err.Number = 0 Then

            If CellToFill.Value <> "" Then

                CellToFill.Value = CellToFill.Value & ","

                CellToFill.Value = CellToFill.Value & TableEntry

            Else

                CellToFill.Value = TableEntry

            End If

        Else

            MisMatchCounter = MisMatchCounter + 1

            Sheets("Errors").Cells(MisMatchCounter, 1).Value = ListRow

            Sheets("Errors").Cells(MisMatchCounter, 2).Value = Cells(ListRow, 1)

            Sheets("Errors").Cells(MisMatchCounter, 3).Value = Cells(ListRow, 2)

            Sheets("Errors").Cells(MisMatchCounter, 4).Value = Cells(ListRow, 3)

            Sheets("Errors").Cells(MisMatchCounter, 5).Value = Cells(ListRow, 4)

        End If

    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

    ListRow = ListRow + 1

Loop
```

Code Example 2:

```
Sub CreateManualMatrix()

    Dim TableRow, TableColumn As Integer

    Dim TableEntry As String

    Dim CellToFill As Range

    'Sheet is called Lijst

    'Column A is names for top row

    'Column B is names for left column

    'Column C is value for Matrix



    'Matrix Top Row starts at H1

    'Matrix Left Column starts at G2



    MatrixLastColAddress = Range("H1").End(xlToRight).Address

    MatrixLastRow = Range("G65536").End(xlUp).Row

    LijstReadColumn = 3

    LijstCurrentRow = 2 'make 1 if no header is used

    Do Until Sheets("Lijst").Cells(LijstCurrentRow, 1).Value = ""

        ' Get table entry from third column of list.

        TableEntry = Sheets("Lijst").Cells(LijstCurrentRow, LijstReadColumn).Value

        ' Get position of Employee name within Matrix.

        TableColumn = Application.Match(Sheets("Lijst").Cells(LijstCurrentRow, 1), Range("H1:" & MatrixLastColAddress), 0)

        ' Get position of Qualification Name within Matrix titles.

        TableRow = Application.Match(Sheets("Lijst").Cells(LijstCurrentRow, 2), Range("G2:G" & MatrixLastRow), 0)

        Set CellToFill = Range("G1").Offset(TableRow, TableColumn)

        ' If there's already an entry in the cell, separate it from the new entry with a comma and space.

        If CellToFill.Value <> "" Then CellToFill.Value = CellToFill.Value & ","

        ' Add the new entry to the cell.

        CellToFill.Value = CellToFill.Value & TableEntry

        LijstCurrentRow = LijstCurrentRow + 1

    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no way to check if the query is fine, but more or less would be a query like this:

```
SELECT t1.Location, MAX(t1.Computers), MAX(t1.Printers),  MAX(t1.Software)

FROM (
SELECT
 t.Location,
 CASE WHEN t.Category = 'Computers' THEN
   t.Supplier
 END Computers,

 CASE WHEN t.Category = 'Printers' THEN
   t.Supplier
 END Printers,

 CASE WHEN t.Category = 'Software' THEN
   t.Supplier
 END Software,
FROM
YOUR_TABLE t
) t1
GROUP BY t1.Location
```

Answer (score 0):

What you seek is often called a crosstab. This can be done statically like so:

```
Select Location
    , Min( Case When Category = 'Computers' Then Supplier End ) As Computers
    , Min( Case When Category = 'Printers' Then Supplier End ) As Printers
    , Min( Case When Category = 'Software' Then Supplier End ) As Software
From MyTable
Group By Location
```

However, if what you seek is to have a dynamic number of categories (and thus columns), this cannot be done natively in SQL. This later solution is called a dynamic crosstab. The best approach is either to build the SQL statement akin to the static version above in your middle-tier or using a reporting tool which will do the same.