# Transpose columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
name, a
v1, 1
name, b
v1, 1
v2, 5
name, c
v1, 4
v2, 6
name, d
v2, 8
v3, asdf
```

Using Excel or LibreOffice, how can I transform it into this:

```
name, v1, v2, v3
a, 1,  ,
b, 1, 5,
c, 4, 6,
d,  , 8, asdf
```

I've been looking for the keyword transpose, but it seems that is not the right keyword to search for - all of the guides show only how to do a full transpose, which is not what I want.

I've also found this question, but it assumes very clean data and must be manually tuned for the number of columns: [Specific Transpose in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24956111/specific-transpose-in-excel)

I don't know the number of columns ahead of time, and some of the cells may be missing.

Comment: Are all the values numbers in your data?

Comment: No, updated question

Comment: If they were all numbers, you could do it with a pivot table. Alas, I believe VBA is the answer.

Comment: Is the original and final data in a single column?  Does there need to be spaces after the commas?  Or are you just going to write it back as a CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

My formula based approach with following data layout:

[image]

Columns `A` and `B` are imported from CSV file.

Formula in helper `C` column:

```
=IF(A2="name",B2,C1)
```

Formulas in `F1` and `F2` count unique entries in `A` and `C` columns, they are not necessary to create output table (both array formulas confirmed with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`):

```
=SUM(1/COUNTIF(C2:C12,C2:C12))

=SUM(1/COUNTIF(A2:A12,A2:A12))
```

Row headers - unique values from `C` column (`E6`, confirmed with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`, and dragged down)

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$12, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($E$5:E5, $C$2:$C$12), 0)),"")
```

Colummn headers - unique values from `A` column (`F5`, confirmed with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`, and dragged right)

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$12, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($E$5:E5, $A$2:$A$12), 0)),"")
```

Two column `INDEX`/`MATCH` combination to fill output table (`F6`, confirmed with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`, and dragged right and down):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$12,MATCH(F$5&$E6,$A$2:$A$12&$C$2:$C$12,0)),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform two actions to achieve your goal:

### 1. Consolidate your data

Move the different data types to separate columns. You will have three new columns with formulas:

- Name: `=IF(A2="name",B2,C1)`
- V:           `=IF(A2="name","",A2)`
- Value: `=IF(A2="name","",B2)`

[image]

### 2. Create pivot table

Here you can't work with standard pivot tables as values can be text too, there are several tutorials on creating it:

- an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7744347/4721734) from Rober Ilbrink on Stackoverflow with VBA
- another [solution](http://www.clearlyandsimply.com/clearly_and_simply/2011/06/emulate-excel-pivot-tables-with-texts-in-the-value-area-using-vba.html) from clearlyandsimply.com again with VBA

Answer (score 0):

I took your request quite literally.  Since you wanted to use Excel to "transform" a CSV file from looking like your first example to looking like your second example, I used Excel VBA to:

- Open the original CSV file
- Read it line by line, and build up an object consisting of items of each `name`
- Insert a label line in the results array
- Reconstruct the individual lines, consisting of `Name` and the `V's`
- Write the lines to a new CSV file, with the formatting you requested.

If you open the CSV files in Notepad, you can see the results.

Be sure to set a reference to Windows Scripting Runtime to access the FileSystemObject.

---

```
Option Explicit
'SET REFERENCE to Windows Scripting Runtime
'  Under Tools/References in the main menu above
Sub ChangeCSV()
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject, F As File, TS As TextStream
    Dim FN As String
    Dim V As Variant
    Dim S As String
    Dim vRes() As Variant

    Dim cI As cItem, colI As Collection
    Dim bFirstName As Boolean
    Dim I As Long, J As Long

bFirstName = True

'Get File
FN = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSV Files (*.csv), *.csv")

'Read file into textstream
Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
Set TS = FSO.OpenTextFile(FN, ForReading)
Set colI = New Collection


Do Until TS.AtEndOfStream
    S = TS.ReadLine
    'Remove leading and trailing quote marks, if present
    'If Left(S, 1) = """" Then S = Mid(S, 2)
    'If Right(S, 1) = """" Then S = Left(S, Len(S) - 1)

    If Not S = "" Then 'skip empty lines
        V = Split(S, ",")
        If Trim(V(0)) = "name" Then
            If bFirstName = False Then colI.Add cI 'don't add if first name
            bFirstName = False
            Set cI = New cItem
        End If
        CallByName cI, CStr(Trim(V(0))), VbLet, Trim(V(1))
    End If
Loop
    colI.Add cI

'Compile results
ReDim vRes(0 To colI.Count, 1 To 4)
    vRes(0, 1) = "Name"
    vRes(0, 2) = "V1"
    vRes(0, 3) = "V2"
    vRes(0, 4) = "V3"
    For I = 1 To colI.Count
        With colI(I)
            vRes(I, 1) = .Name
            vRes(I, 2) = .V1
            vRes(I, 3) = .V2
            vRes(I, 4) = .V3
        End With
    Next I

'Note different file name
Set TS = FSO.CreateTextFile(Left(FN, Len(FN) - 4) & "MOD.csv", True)
    For I = 0 To UBound(vRes)
        V = Empty
        ReDim V(1 To 4)
        For J = 1 To 4
            V(J) = vRes(I, J)
        Next J

        TS.WriteLine Join(V, ",")
    Next I
TS.Close
Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

---